# Bypass list for Ruleset not applying to status checks and pull requests

Tags: github, continuous-integration, repository, continuous-deployment, github-rulesets

I have a repository with the default branch of main. I have created a ruleset to protect the main branch. In this ruleset, I have configured the following:

- Require a PR before merging

  - Also require a code review from a codeowner
- Require status checks to pass

  - I have 3 status checks listed here

There is a github user in our organization that is strictly for automation purposes only, that I would like to allow to push to the main branch and bypass all of these rules. I have placed said user in their own team in our organization, and then placed that team inside the bypass list for the ruleset.

However, during the rule evaluations, it is showing up as failing the two checks I have listed above despite being in the bypass list. Is there something I am missing? My understanding is that the bypass list allows specific teams to ignore the rulesets for that branch.

Comment: "allowed to ignore" and "doesn't apply at all" are two different things. The user should be able to complete the pull request by selecting the "bypass" option. But the rules will still evaluate. From the docs: "The actor can then choose to bypass any branch protections and merge that pull request." https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/creating-rulesets-for-a-repository#granting-bypass-permissions-for-your-ruleset